# ToUpper method's dot notation

Tags: c#, string

The goal is to catch a user's response and make all the letters in it uppercase. How to know in what part of the equation to add this particular method through dot notation?

Why does this work

```
Console.Write("YES or NO: ");
string noiseChoice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
```

and this does not

```
Console.Write("YES or NO: ");
string noiseChoice.ToUpper() = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: `string noiseChoice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();` says "please read a line from the console - and then make it upper case" (you read the code to the right of `=` from left to right). The second code sample, well it doesn't make sense - so you tell us what you _think_ it should do.

Comment: BTW, you should use `?.ToUpper` not `ToUpper`, in case `Console.ReadLine` returns `null`.

Comment: If you are new to programming, do code step by step instead. There is no shame in that. `var input = Console.ReadLine(); var noiseChoice = input?.ToUpper();` You can use `var` or `string` - whatever you prefer.

Comment: Pretty unlikely that the user will hit Ctrl Z though, or that that this is a space shuttle control program with dire consequences if they do! :)

Comment: the second one does not work because it's not valid syntax because that's just how the language was defined. also: it's not an _equation_. it's an _assignment_.

Comment: Unlikely @CaiusJard - but may as well start good habits.

Comment: Understand, but wary of overloading beginners with too much - code with a null coalesce in every possible place is quite hard to read and follow for a newbie.

Comment: Oh, absolutely - my "every possible place" was in reference  to  that thing where one tells a newbie something and then *they* overuse it. I should have made that clear

Comment: Ah, fair point @CaiusJard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is the "thing inside thing" accessor

```
person.Name
person.GetName()
```

Means "the name property inside person" or "the GetName method inside person"

It is not a statement on its own. To make it a statement we have to read its value or assign to it

```
person.Name = "John";  //assignment

string n = person.Name; //reading
Print(person.Name); //read name and send into Print method as parameter
```

Method calls cannot be assigned to

If this were math class and you had some function like `sqrt()` that takes in a number and puts out a number, it doesn't make sense to say:

```
sqrt(4) = 27;
```

`=` here is assignment, not comparison; you cannot assign to the result of calling a method

When you write:

```
string name
```

You're declaring a variable called name of type string. This is the only thing you can do at this point and the next thing you type(if you're going to type anything at all) other than a semicolon to end the statement, must be an =

```
string name = "John";

string name;     //valid to write nothing
name = "John";
```

You cannot call a method on a variable you're declaring:

```
string name.Method() //no
```

Your "dot" isn't attached to the `ToUpper`, or the `name` - it's the "thing between" that lets you say "thing on the right inside the thing on the left", and it gives you access into "whatever the thing on the left is" which means it can be chained and the "thing on the left" changes

```
int lengthWithoutA = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().Replace("A","").Length;
```

- ReadLine returns a string. Dotting on it gets us access to anything inside a string class, like ToUpper
- ToUpper takes no parameters and returns another string
- We can call Replace on this new uppercase string, Replace is a method that takes two parameters and returns a string that (in this case) has all its A removed
- We then access the Length property of this new string which returns an integer.
- Finally, we store this Integer into the `lengthWithoutA` variable.

This is the only resultant output of this line; what the user typed, the uppercase version, the no-A version - they were all lost after we got the length and assigned it. The dot dot dot just had them as intermediary steps and we captured only the final output, by assigning it into a variable

Lines of code are evaluated left to right but you should appreciate that in an assignment operation like the above the right hand side of the assignment has to be evaluated first, to generate the value that will be assigned

It's probably also important to appreciate that some methods modify the objects they're called on, and others return a new version of the object. Strings don't change after they're created, so:

```
string name = "John";
name.ToUpper();
```

That code above is valid but it doesn't alter the name; strings don't change. Calling ToUpper returned a new string JOHN. We didn't assign it or use its value so it was thrown away

---

Interesting fact that lots of people forget. In c# assigning a value returns the value that was assigned. It means this can work:

```
string name = person.Name = "John";
```

Both `name` and `person.Name` end up as John because the assignment `person.Name = "John"` is done and returns `"John"` as a value that is then assigned into `name`

If you did this:

```
string name = (person.Name = "John").ToUpper()
```

person.Name would again be John because that assignment is done first (thanks to the parentheses) and it returns "John" as a string which then has ToUpper called on it, so `name` would end up as "JOHN"

Hopefully this gives some insight into the order of operations and use of dot, but if there's anything missing, add a comment

Answer (score 1):

```
string noiseChoice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
```

This is not an *equation*, it is an *asignment*. It has a defined order of execution:

First, the expression on the right-hand side of the equals sign `=` is evaluated, and it is evaluated from left to right:

1. The runtime "takes" the `Console` class.
2. It then calls its `ReadLine` method to read input from the user until they press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. On that input, it calls the `ToUpper` method in order to transform the input to upper-case and return that input.

This last step is the result of the expression on the right-hand side of `=`.

The runtime will then proceed to assign that result to the *writeable target* on the left-hand side.

In your case, that target is a variable; it could also be a couple of other things. It could, however, *not* be an arbitrary expression, such as a function call, because you cannot *assign* a value to a function call.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an "equation" in the mathematical sense:

```
string noiseChoice = Console.ReadLine();
```

The equal sign does not mean "these things are equal". It means "put the thing on the right into the thing on the left". The thing on the left (`string noiseChoice`) declares a *variable* (into which you can put stuff) called `noiseChoice`, and the thing on the right (`Console.ReadLine()`) gives you the user input. So the whole thing means "put the user input into the variable called `noiseChoice`".

Now to make the user input uppercase, it is obvious that you should add it to the right side,

```
string noiseChoice = Console.ReadLine().ToUpperCase();
```

because that is the thing you are putting into `noiseChoice`. You want to put "the user input uppercased" into `noiseChoice`.

If you did:

```
string noiseChoice.ToUpperCase() = Console.ReadLine();
```

That would be declaring a variable called `noiseChoice.ToUpperCase()`, and putting the user input in it, which isn't what you want, not to mention that variable names can't have `.` or `()`, so you can't even do that...